# How to place a web browser inside an iphone application?

Tags: iphone, xcode

such that when the user open the application the website referenced will be loaded in the web browser
I know the code the will open a URL with in an application

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];
```

But this is not what I need I need the application to display the web browser within its form.

Comment: Have you tried UIWebView?(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only to show one page I suggest you should use `ModalViewController` to present the page inside your app and put a `UIWebView` in it.

If you are to render the web page as an application than you should use `UIWebView`

If you want to present some pages but also want to make use of navigation functions of the safari inside your app you can use `DLWebView` framework which suppors ModalView with navigation function.

Here you can watch the video how it works: http://dlinsin.github.com/2011/04/24/DLWebView.html

Answer (score 0):

You need `UIWebView` class : [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also you can try to search for a ready webview with all needful buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `UIWebView`?

If you need browser functionality within your own app, you will need to create your own, i.e. it's not possible to embed the Safari browser within a view in your own app.